# Why don't $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ have the Archimedean property?

Tags: real-analysis

I was given this definition of a set $E$ that has the Archimedean property:

> If $x \in E$, and $\epsilon \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ then $\exists n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n \cdot \epsilon > x$.

It just seems to me that $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ have this property. Is there a counter example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what makes you think that $\mathbb{N}$ of $\mathbb{Z}$ don't have the archimedean property, but they do. Pedagogically, sometimes one shows that $\mathbb{N}$ has the archimedian property first, on the way to proving that the reals also have this property. [This depends of course on whether one constructs the reals or axiomatically defines the reals, etc.]